# ¿Qué hacer con una pregunta que hice, cuya solución no tiene nada que ver con mi pregunta?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-preguntas

Hace unos días hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193877/java-heap-space-wildfly-12-itextpdf).

Al final el error era que estaba intentando crear un pdf de unas 130.000 páginas, encontré el error en una query. Lo que ocurre es que este error solo se daba en un servidor de producción y en desarrollo no lo vi claro.

Entonces, ¿qué hago con la pregunta? ¿la cierro? ¿la elimino? ¿Cuál es la acción mas adecuada?

Comment: Tienes dos opciones. Eliminarla (tiene una respuesta, pero al no tener votos creo que no es impedimento), o añadir una respuesta tu mismo y aceptarla. En realidad depende solo de ti, es tu pregunta :)

Comment: Estoy con @Pikoh. Si crees que alguien va a aprender algo de tu explicación del error, publica una respuesta detallándolo. En caso contrario, coméntaselo a quien te respondió (por deferencia, yo incluso intentaría "compensar" su tiempo mirando si hay alguna publicación suya votable) y posteriormente elimina la pregunta. Siempre es bueno dejar un comentario explicando qué pasó, pues aunque la elimines, la gente con más de 10 K de reputación la podrá ver y puede que les extrañe ver un "eliminada" sin mayor explicación.

Comment: @fedorqui Pues creo que la voy a eliminar, ya que la solución dista mucho de la pregunta.

Comment: @nachfren pero puedes agregar tu propia respuesta explicando la situación, aunque en este caso el error no se puede determinar con la información de la pregunta, recuerda que un motivo de cierre es "No relacionado: Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir", saludos.

Comment: Gracias a todos, al final avise al usuario que me contestó y eliminé la pregunta.

Comment: Yo estuve en tu misma situación, respondí mi pregunta y me bombardearon a votos negativos